# Apache Directory vs Microsoft Active Directory vs IBM Tivoli Directory vs Oracle Internet Directory

Tags: active-directory, directory, comparison, tivoli

What are the points we should to consider when, looking for suitable directory service.

If you have idea about differences among these directory service (Apache Directory , Microsoft Active Directory , IBM Tivoli Directory , Oracle Internet Directory), please explain.

Best regards

Comment: Are you asking about their programming interfaces? If not, this probably belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you intend to use the directory service for?

If you are using it to manage Windows workstations within a reasonably local network, then Active Directory is probably the way to go.

If you need it to run on anything other than Windows, then look elsewhere.

If you have fairly flexible replication and distributed placement needs, then Novell eDirectory is quite good at it.

OID and Tivoli are both good directory services as well.  It just depends on what you intend to use it for, and what systems you have experience with.